# Bash block redirection and piping

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm learning bash redirection. I expect the following code to do the equivalent of `ls | grep foo | grep bar`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

{
    {
        ls | grep foo
    } 2>&1 1>&4 | grep bar
} 4>&1
```

This matches foo but not foo and bar. I thought this will work since `2>&1` copies pipe in fd 1 to fd 2, and then we reset fd 1 to stdout.

Can you fix this code while keeping the braces(contexts)? If I remove `2>&1 1>&4` it works as expected. But I would like to learn.

I think on the left side of pipe | it only expects stdout so even if I copy the pipe to fd 2, it will still only look for fd 1 on the left side of pipe.

Refer: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#an_example

In the referenced link above, there is a diagram where fd 2 of cmd1 points to fd 0 of cmd3. I'm trying to verify this using my example.

Comment: I don't see how you arrived at your expectation - there is no duplication of `ls` output (unlike say, `zsh`, where multiple redirections could be used to send the same output to multiple commands), so since you have only one invocation of `ls` in your script, only one of `ls | grep \~; ls | grep sh$` would be correct.

Comment: @muru yes i think it is doing `ls | grep \~ | grep sh$`

Comment: welcome to unix.se! you : first you create a fd4 duplicating fd1, ie : 4 now goes to where 1 is currently going (stdout by default). Then you : 2>&1 : 2 goes to where 1 is now pointing (ie, stdout). then 1>&4: 1 now goes to fd 4 (the one of the surrounding shell). you grep bar : on stdin (fd1), so on stderr only of the { ls | grep foo } .... I think you should put the | grep bar after the 4>&1

Comment: You may want to read what the original usenet discussion was about and that wiki page from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

your attempt:

```
{
    {
        ls | grep foo # goes to stdout (fd 1)
    } 2>&1 1>&4 | grep bar  # at this level: 2 now points to where fd1 is pointing (stdout), and 1 is *then* directed to the new fd 4 (ie to stdin of the outside curly)
} 4>&1  ## at this shell 'level', a new fd 4 is now pointing to where 1 is pointing: stdout
```

: the grep bar is therefor done only on stderr of the { ls | grep foo }, and thus on an empty stdin, as only stderr of the { ls | grep foo } goes to stdout of the { ls | grep foo }. This will never see filenames. ths filenames goes to fd 4
try:

```
{
    {
        ls | grep foo
    } 2>&1 1>&4
} 4>&1 | grep bar
```

or

```
{
    {
        ls | grep foo
    } 2>&1 1>&4 | <&4 grep bar
} 4>&1
```

and compare...

note: if you meant for stderr of the inner commands to also go to stdout, it needs to be duplicated in 2nd position:  1>&4 2>&1 [ie : 1 now goes to fd 4, and then 2 goes to where 1 is now pointing, ie fd 4 as well]

Comment: As far as i know `2>&1` copies pipe in fd  1 to fd 2 because it is left side of pipe |.

Comment: `<&4 grep bar`, would redirect `grep` stdin to the same resource as open on the outer stdout, so in the OP's example `/dev/pts/5` so read what you type. In the general case (not in a terminal), it would cause `grep` to fail as that *open file description* would be open  in write mode and `grep` would try to read from it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: thx, I said to try those 2 and compare: because i expect the one with <&4 grep bar : to **not** work (as there are no fd 4 defined at this level, and the pipe has nothing to carry over to the right side). i have a bit trouble understanding the rest of your remark though ... why would this be always pts/5 ? and why is a "<" opening in write mode?

Comment: @LoganLee : not because it is left of the pipe. any "x>&y" : is a way to tell "now x points to where y is **currently** pointing at". ie, it copies the destination of y into x.  The order of those redirections matter: `ls -ld / /inexistant 2>&1 >/dev/null`  redirects fd2 to stdout (as fd1 goes to stdout at first) and *then* redirects 1 to /dev/null : So you only see on stdout: the error message "ls: cannot access '/inexestant': No such file or directory" (but not the info of "/", which goes, via fd1, to /dev/null). If you put >/dev/null 2>&1: boh fd 1 and 2 are discarded by going to /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather the following is true.

This

```
{
    {
        ls | grep foo
    } 2>&1 1>&4 | grep bar
} 4>&1
```

is equivalent to

```
(ls | grep foo 2>&1 1>&4 | grep bar) 4>&1
```

And it fails because fd 4 is, for instance, /dev/pts/0 and 1>&4 will result in fd 1 having the same /dev/pts/0 instead of pipe.

Comment: Note that `... { ls | grep foo; } 2>&1 ...` sends the standard error stream of _both_ `ls` and `grep` to `grep bar`, while `... ls | grep foo 2>&1 ...` only sends to `grep bar` the standard error of `grep foo` (`ls`' standard error is not redirected).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are expecting the re-direction to make a copy of the data? Consider using `tee`.
As you are learning, I won't spoil things by saying more.

Also use `shellcheck` to check your code. It will help you find most errors more quickly.